# Solve $y'(x)=y(x)f(x)+y^2(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> We consider the equation
>   $$y'(x)=y(x)f(x)+y^2(x)$$
>   with $y(0)=y_0\in\mathbb R$ and $f\in\mathcal C^0(\mathbb R)$.
>
> Give a necessary and sufficient condition on $f$ and $y_0$ for that the solution $y(x)$ is defined for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$.

The equation is equivalent at $\frac{y'(x)}{y^2(x)}=\frac{f(x)}{y(x)}+1$ with $y(x)\neq 0$.

First I set $z(x)=\frac{1}{y(x)}$ and thus the system become

$$\begin{cases}z(x)=\frac{1}{y(x)}\\ z'(x)+f(x)z(x)=-1\end{cases}$$

I solve the homogenous solution thus I have

$$\frac{z'(x)}{z(x)}=-f(x)\implies \ln(z(x))=-\int^x f(t)dt\implies z(x)=e^{-\int f(t)dt}$$

Then, how can I found the boundary of the integral (I'm not sure if the expression exist, but how can I find the $a$ and $b$ in $\int_a^b f(t)dt$ ?

Then, a particular solution is given by $w(t)=1$ and thus
$$af(x)=-1\implies a=\frac{-1}{f(x)}$$ then I get
$$z(x)=e^{-\int f(t)dt}-\frac{1}{f(x)}.$$

How can I conclude now ?

Answer (score 0):

$\int f(t)\,dt$ is he indefinite integral of $f$, which represents the set of all its primitives. You want to choose one of them. Since the initial condition is give at $x=0$, it is natural to take $\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$. The solution of $z'+f\,z=0$ is then
$$
z(x)=C\,e^{-\int_0^xf(t)\,dt}.
$$
To find a particular solution let
$$
z(x)=w(x)e^{-\int_0^xf(t)\,dt}.
$$
This leads to $$
w'(x)=-e^{\int_0^xf(t)\,dt}\implies w(x)=-\int_0^xe^{\int_0^tf(s)\,ds}\,dt
$$
and
$$
z(x)=e^{-\int_0^xf(t)\,dt}\Bigl(C-\int_0^xe^{\int_0^tf(s)\,ds}\,dt\Bigr).
$$

Comment: so what are the conditions on $f$ and $y_0$ for the solution to exist for all $x?$

Comment: Write $y$. Find $C$ in terms of $y_0$. The expression will have a denominator: it should not vanish.

Comment: ok, then I get $$\ln(y(x))=\int e^{-\int_0^x f(t)ft}(C-\int_0^x e^{\int_0^t f(s)ds}dt)dx+C\implies y_0\exp\left(\int e^{-\int_0^x f(t)ft}(C-\int_0^x e^{\int_0^t f(s)ds}dt)dx\right)$$ but how can I conclude ?